# Bitcoin transaction invalid no confirmations

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, cash-app

Can some please help I had bitcoin sent to cash app wallet cash app rejected the deposit and reversed the deposit. Well the reversal never did confirm on the blockchain it show invalid my BTC is stuck this is the hash:
fc10ee8537db255493f1aeb9e07297f18714dd0f715698c8732c13de0b3cba3b.       What can I do to get my bitcoin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Answer (score 1):

The recipient address [`bc1qpwzp…kacv`](https://mempool.space/address/bc1qpwzp3mq59efgcvneqnuzuepmtz3qcs7ld0kacv) which was originally paid by the transaction that became invalid [`fc10…ba3b`](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/fc10ee8537db255493f1aeb9e07297f18714dd0f715698c8732c13de0b3cba3b)
later got paid a slightly larger amount (0.00500000 BTC instead of 0.00499346
BTC) by another transaction [`31d1…fdb6`](https://mempool.space/tx/31d156e9a2d9b976c25a6ce29b404ffbdb77b25ab24980937c6f136c77f8fdb6).

If you were expecting to get paid about 5 m₿ to [`bc1qpwzp…kacv`](https://mempool.space/address/bc1qpwzp3mq59efgcvneqnuzuepmtz3qcs7ld0kacv), it looks to me like you got paid on the 22nd of February, and you spent those funds on the same day in transaction [`7953…c8c1`](https://mempool.space/tx/79535391819d69869d61b971b8e68775539933f0d488b407ec12fd81ca60c8c1).

Comment: Okay so here is another problem the original transaction was a withdraw from a casino. It was rejected from cash app and sent back to the casino they are saying I owe them the balance

Comment: That sounds like a very different matter. Unfortunately, we have no insight into the state of your customer relationships with either CashApp or the casino and cannot help you with that.